# Which is the best syntax to use for jQuery conditional statements?

Tags: jquery, syntax, conditional-statements

I come from a Perl coders background, so out of habit I always use curly brackets to enclose the actions taken when a conditional statement returns a true. For example, and using jQuery, as this is where I need an explanation as to the difference, this two statements are both equivalent and of valid syntax.

```
if ($('#user_agreement').is(':checked')) { $('#thanks_message').show(); }  

if ($('#user_agreement').is(':checked')) $('#thanks_message').show();
```

Are my old habits betraying me, and I'm just writting unnecessary extra code without any advantage? Or is one method more effective, or considered more standard to good coding practices? I would really like to understand any differences between the two different syntactical approaches, especially when they both work just as well.

Comment: The first case. It's because in a future refactoring it prevent a possible bug of miss brackets

Comment: This is not question about jQuery syntax, more about javascript and statements question. jsLint suggest using brackets, jsHint didn't force them so better talk with your workmates. And

Comment: @Allyson de Paula. I hope this is true, as that would mean my old programming habits are still an attribute to me, rather than a hinderance.

Comment: @Eraden. Not true, as I am speaking (see OP) strictly in the context of jQuery. I know vanilla javascript up, down, and sideways, and it has also served to form my habit of coding with the brackets just as Perl has.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I misunderstand title.

Comment: For this question it makes no difference whether you're using jQuery or not. It's JavaScript code either way, and whatever choices you make about code style pertain identically to jQuery or any other JavaScript code.

Comment: @Michael Geary. Not true, the impact of overused jQuery can severely impede the performance of your script! As an example, a standard 'for' loop using vanilla javascript is about four times faster than using it's jQuery '.each' function counterpart. It's the overall recipe that makes the finest cake.

Comment: @Michael Geary. Just to append, the 'for' loop is faster, as it is not having to make a library call as with jQuery.

Comment: I wasn't talking about whether you should use jQuery or not. Your question wasn't about whether one should use jQuery - you were asking about code formatting. My point was that *with regard to code formatting*, it makes no difference whether you use jQuery or not. jQuery does not have a separate way of writing code that is different from JavaScript, because jQuery and the code that uses it are simply JavaScript. Whatever choices you make in formatting your JavaScript code should be the same whether jQuery is involved or not.

Comment: @Michael Geary. Yes, I am quite aware that jQuery is javascript, but jQuery is NOT the same 'syntactically', and that is exactly what it is... a library of shorthand javascript methods. The very motto of the jQuery folks from the go get was 'Do More... Write Less...', directly implying a change in syntax to invoke standard javascript functions. jQuery IS a separate way of writting code for the SAME language.

Comment: Don't be misled by a marketing slogan. jQuery doesn't change or introduce any new syntax. There aren't any code formatting issues that apply to "jQuery code" as opposed to JavaScript code. A function that accepts a string and returns an object isn't new. Chaining isn't new. None of the syntax is new, it's just a bunch of functions and objects like any other JavaScript library. So the code formatting issues really are the same, unless you decide for some reason that you want to format "jQuery code" differently from other JavaScript code. But why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sorry to say, but this has nothing to do with jQuery. This is pure Javascript, through and through. But anyway, here's your answer:

They do the same thing.

HOWEVER.

- The second option, without the curly braces, can only be used for one
  statement of code. As soon as the fist semi-colon is hit, the rest of the
  code is outside of the `if` statement.
- The second option isn't even really frowned upon, but it really
  should be. It could save developers hours of looking through their
  code only to realize that they accidentally included a semi-colon
  right after the `if` statement. (i.e. they did something unfortunate like:

->

```
if ( $("#user_agreement").is(':checked')); $("#thanks_message").show();
```

- The first option allows you to add more lines of code to the conditional statement without having to painstakingly add more curly braces.
- Curly braces simply make your code clearer, especially as in the next bullet ->
- And finally, nesting these thing becomes incredibly confusing. For example:

->

```
if(var1 == 'string1') 
    console.log("string1");
    if(var2 == 'string2')
        console.log("string2");
else 
    console.log("else");
```

The indentation indicates the else block goes with the outside `if`--but it actually goes with the inside `if`.

Comment: And of course, there's the advantage of clarity in the curly braces option :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to be specific in your answer, especially in pointing out the importance of keeping any nesting easy to follow (kudos), as larger projects almost always include an incredible amount of nesting.

Comment: I appreciate it. Good luck in your future coding endeavors :)

Answer (score 1):

They are indeed both valid, tho I would personally advice for the usage of curly brackets. They make it clearer which lines are part of the `if`. 
This however is a very personal issue. Some people prefer to use them, others don't.

The advantage of placing the curly brackets is that your code can become clearer (but in that case, I would also advise the usage of newlines.

Comment: I agree with you on the usage to empart clarity of code, and normally I do use newlines and white space for the sake of the coder that comes behind me and needs to update the code. Been there more times than I can count. I only use single line statements as in the example, when there is only one action to invoke, such as calling another function.

Answer (score 0):

there is a single statement like

```
if ( $("#user_agreement").is(':checked')) { $("#thanks_message").show(); }
```

There is no need to put braces

There are more than one statement like

```
  if ( $("#user_agreement").is(':checked')) { 
   $("#thanks_message").show(); 
   $("#thanks_message").show(); 
  $("#thanks_message").show(); 
     $("#thanks_message").show(); 
 }
```

You should use braces

Answer (score 0):

Have to agree there's no reason to solve this using jquery when plain js is so obvious and readable, but just for the sake of demonstration here's a pure jquery equivalent using [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).  Sometimes a long jquery chaining operation makes it undesirable to break the chain to plain js so this technique is useful (even if not what the method was designed for) for inserting a conditional without breaking the chain.  To move on with the chain you'll need to add an [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) afterward to restore the original selector.

your expression ....

```
if ($('#user_agreement').is(':checked')) {
   $('#thanks_message')
      .show();
}
```

using only jquery...

```
$('#thanks_message')
   .filter(function(){return $('#user_agreement').is(':checked');})
      .show();
```

working example:

> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doJxmW

by the way I have in the past created a plugin to simplify the syntax for such an operation....

```
$.fn.iff = function (test) {
   return this.filter(function() {return test;} );
};
```

which allows this more readable syntax...

```
$('#thanks_message')
   .iff($('#user_agreement').is(':checked'))
      .show();
```

if you are returning the query object be sure to use `.end()` to restore the original object

```
return this
   .iff(someTest)
      .show()
      .end();
```